# React native error in launching app with android emulator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I get following error when I run `react-native run-android` in CMD(windows command prompt)

```
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

What caused This problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

check your device connected or not by execute below command in cmd

> adb devices

if adb not found then open below dir

> C:\Users\MANGO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

then check device connected or not

then you can lunch your app
i hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Set the sdk platform tools path in system variable inside Enviroment variable.
With this you can check the connected devices from command promt.

Note: Make sure you have connected your device to PC with USB debugging On from developer menu. You can follow this [link](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/enabling_usb_debugging_on_an_android_device.html)

Then follow following steps.

1. From command prompt type " adb devices ", if you are connecting the real android device first time then inside your device there will be a RSA key generated which you have to click "OK".
2. Then to confirm from devices you can again type adb devices if all went good it will show your device.
3. Move to your project folder from command prompt and then run your app from command prompt.

Comment: what would be the name of that path?

Comment: In system variables, you do not need to write the name. Just add that path